# How to get the necessary value of very unsual format text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk, cmd

I have an output which is a text file like this (`C:\test.txt`)

```
database_name                                                                                                                   |database_size     |unallocated space 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------|------------------
web                                                                                                                     |          11120.00 MB       |11157.80 MB       

(1 sˆ—‚³‚ê‚Ü‚µ‚½)
reserved          |data              |index_size        |unused            
------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------
111360 KB         |11560 KB          |11160 KB          |111640 KB          

(1 sˆ—‚³‚ê‚Ü‚µ‚½)
```

Needless to say, this was a mess.
However, I would like to get the value of "unused" column which is 111640.

My machine is Windows, I tried the following code but it didn't give me anything:

```
@echo off
SET _c=
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%G IN (C:\test.txt) DO (
    IF DEFINED _c <nul set /p z=", "
    <nul set /p z=%%G
    SET _c=1
)
```

Someone can tell me how to get this value?

Comment: There should be some way with `FINDSTR` and parameters `/r` and a regex something like `[0-9]* KB$`

Comment: Can you use `gawk`? Also is this file ended by carriage returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (simpler) one, just for the collection!

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('"setx /F test.txt dummyVar /R 2,3 unused /D ^|"') do set "col=%%a" & goto continue
:continue

set "col=%col:~0,-1%"
echo %col%
```

The desired token is two (2) lines below the search one. The line of the desired token have *two tokens* per each one in the search line. For this reason, the token offset is 3 (instead of 0).

A detailed explanation of this method is given at [this site](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5083)

---

**EDIT**: *New method added*

This simple and standard method also works because the desired value is the *only seventh token* in the file!

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=7 delims=| " %%a in (test.txt) do set "col=%%a"
echo %col%
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is tagged [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), how about

```
awk -F "|" "$NF ~ /unused/{p=1} p && /[0-9]/ { print $NF; p = 0 }" messyfile.txt
```

I hope double quotes are appropriate for Windows; on U*x I would use single quotes throughout.

`-F` sets the field separator, `NF` is the number of fields; so `$NF` examines the last field on each line. If we see `unused` in the last field, start looking for a number. When we see a line which contains at least one number, print the last field from that line.

If this is close enough to what you want, I trust that you can figure out how to tweak it e.g. to remove th `KB` suffix (hint: `sub()` or `split()`).

Comment: @Tiw Thanks for the edit. Cursed be the mobile keyboard.

Comment: Sure thing, I spotted one but not the other though.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Would use this on my Linux machine too.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(I haven't tested this on windows environment).

```
awk '!flag{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/unused/){field=i;flag=1}}} flag && !/^-/{print $field,$(field+1);flag="";exit}'  Input_file
```

You need to change single quotes to `"` in case you are on windows.

***Explanation:*** What this code does is it will look for field number where string `unused` is found and then whatever next line(without `-`) it will print that specific and its next field(which has `kb` etc information in it).  I am not hard coding field number here for `unused` string.

As per @MarkSetchell's comment we could try to create a `code.awk` file and run it like `awk -f code.awk Input_file` where Input_file is the sample file.

```
code.awk
!flag{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/unused/){
      field=i
      flag=1
    }
  }
}
flag && !/^-/{
  print $field,$(field+1)
  flag=""
  exit
}'
```

PS: Fair warning I haven't tested this on windows environment

Comment: @Tiw,  Like tripleee sir  I have added change `'` to `"` in case of windows. since I don't have windows environment with me, I have added fair warning in my solution now + I am checking for online terminal if I get it to check if this runs(windows one).

Comment: You can get around most of Windows' inadequacies by putting your `awk` script in a separate file and running with `awk -f thatFile`... :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, cool, let me try it out too and THANKS a TON for letting me know, will add that in my post now.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, added `.awk` type code now, not tested it though, thanks for letting know. Will try to test it. Kindly feel free to edit or let me know in case you find anything not working in it.

Comment: Please don't make me do it - I don't want to run Windows! :-) The only way I'll run Windows is in VirtualBox then all that nastiness is in a single VMDK file I can easily delete in one go!

Answer (score 1):

Try this batch/cmd version:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%j in ^(C:\test.txt^) do @echo %%j`) do (
    (echo %%i | findstr /R "[0-9][0-9]*" ) && set "thenum=%%i" && goto :outloop
)
:outloop
::echo %thenum%
::pause
```

The value is also saved to the variable `thenum` and can be used later.

Answer (score 1):

This .bat file script might give you what you want.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Select-String -Path '.\test.txt' -Pattern '^\d+ .*\|\d+ .*\|\d+ .*\|(\d+).*$' |" ^
    "ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }"
```

Comment: You could shorten with a non capturing group `(?:)` and a quantifier `{3}` => `-Pattern '^(?:\d+ .*\|){3}(\d+).*$' |"`

Comment: @LotPings - Yes, I thought about that. But, it is not a lot shorter and, to me, it is less obvious what it is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you access to all of the data in your input file by the name of that value:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*" }
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
prev1 ~ /^[-|]+$/ {
    split(prev2,tags)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = tags[i]
        val = $i
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }
}
{ prev2 = prev1; prev1 = $0 }
END {
    for (tag in tag2val) {
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "%s = <%s>\n", tag, val
    }
    print "---"
    print tag2val["unused"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
reserved = <111360 KB>
unallocated space = <11157.80 MB>
database_name = <web>
data = <11560 KB>
database_size = <11120.00 MB>
index_size = <11160 KB>
unused = <111640 KB>
---
111640 KB
```

If you'd like a CSV output, just tweak the END section:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*" }
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
prev1 ~ /^[-|]+$/ {
    split(prev2,tags)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = tags[i]
        val = $i
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }
}
{ prev2 = prev1; prev1 = $0 }
END {
    sep = ""
    for (tag in tag2val) {
        printf "%s%s", sep, tag
        sep = ","
    }
    print ""

    sep = ""
    for (tag in tag2val) {
        printf "%s%s", sep, tag2val[tag]
        sep = ","
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
reserved,unallocated space,database_name,data,database_size,index_size,unused
111360 KB,11157.80 MB,web,11560 KB,11120.00 MB,11160 KB,111640 KB
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. Amazing script.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the file content provided, you don't really need a complex search mask:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "UnUsed="
For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=|" %%A In ('Find " KB"^<"C:\test.txt" 2^>Nul'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do If Not Defined UnUsed Set "UnUsed=%%B"
If Defined UnUsed (Echo=%UnUsed% & Pause)
```

Answer (score 1):

As in a batch file consecutive delimiters are counted as one I'd use

On cmd line

```
for /f "tokens=7 delims=| " %A in ('findstr "KB" C:\test.txt') do @set "unused_KB=%A"
```

In a batch file

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=7 delims=| " %%A in ('findstr "KB" C:\test.txt') do set "unused_KB=%%A"
```